# Store file on several hard drives with Django

Tags: django, hard-drive

I'd like to use several hard drives at the same time with django to store my files. My goal is to store big files on a server and share it on a local network.

I would like to know how to proceed in order to store my files in several disk and how django would react when the first disk is full. The idea would be to fill the first one and then switch to the second one. Obviously, if we remove a file in the first one, we re-use it.

Comment: What will be the scale of this? Regardless, I think the best way to do it is to use LVM, Ceph, etc, in the underlying infrastructure and just show a disk to Django.

Comment: It is just a little local service so your solution will work fine. I keep it in mind. I will still wait to see if a solution through django exist. Thanks.

Comment: My solution will work at any scale. I mentioned scale because you won't deploy, say, Ceph, for just a small service on a single server, but there are alternatives spanning the gamut of what you might want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that django can manage such need "out-of-the-box" but you can probably implement such feature by making your own "UploadHandler"

You can inherit a class from `FileUploadHandler`

```
 from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler
 class MyUploadHandler(FileUploadHandler):

      def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
             """ doc says:
             Receives a “chunk” of data from the file upload.
             raw_data is a byte string containing the uploaded data.
             start is the position in the file where this raw_data chunk begins.
             """
             # Here get a temporary copy of file content

      def file_complete(self, file_size):
          """Called when a file has finished uploading."""
          # Here manage the copy on one of your hard disks
```

In settings.py, define:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'path.to.MyUploadHandler
]
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers